# How can I access which files the user currently has open from an eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm very new to eclipse plugin development, and frankly to eclipse itself. I am trying to find a way to access a list of which files are currently being worked on by the user, and possibly even more specifically, what part of these files (which class, method, block of code, etc.).

I am thinking that I would like to have the plugin grab information on which files are currently open in the tabs, and then go from there, but I can't even figure out how to do this. I've been searching the eclipse documentation at help.eclipse.org, but I still haven't found anything useful for what I want to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
IWorkbenchPage[] pages = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPages();

for (IWorkbenchPage page : pages) {
    IEditorReference[] references = page.getEditorReferences();

    for (IEditorReference reference : references) {
        IEditorInput input = reference.getEditorInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an error at "pages.getEditorReferences()". It says "Cannot invoke getEditorReferences() on the array type IWorkbenchPage[]".

Comment: I fixed the code.  You're not going to get very far creating an Eclipse plug-in until you learn how to read the Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Guide API Reference found in the Eclipse help.

Comment: I'll have to agree with you, but I'm working on that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to walk your way from the workbench to a workbench page ([IWorkbenchPage](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html)), which as a findEditors method.